# JSTL, Beans, and method calls

Tags: java, exception, jsp, jstl, vignette

I'm working on a JSP where I need to call methods on object that come from a Bean. The previous version of the page does not use JSTL and it works properly. My new version has a set up like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="pageBean" scope="request" type="com.epicentric.page.website.PageBean" />
<c:set var="pageDividers" value="<%= pageBean.getPageDividers() %>" />
<c:set var="numColumns" value="${pageDividers.size()}" />
```

The variable `pageDividers` is a `List` object.

I'm encountering this issue: when I ask for `pageDivider`'s size, an exception is thrown. I know this is a simple JTSL error -- what am I doing wrong?

The error message is:

> The function size must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

How do I correctly access or call the methods of my `pageDividers` object?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When using the dot operator for property access in JSTL, `${pageDividers.size}` (no **()** needed) results in a call to a method named `getSize()`.
Since java.util.List offers a method called `size()` (rather than `getSize()`) you won't be able to access the list length by using that code.

---

In order to access to a list size, JSTL offers the **fn:length** function, used like

```
${fn:length(pageDividers)}
```

Note that in order to use the **fn** namespace, you should declare it as follows

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

In addition, the same function can be used with any collection type, and with Strings too.

Comment: Be wary.  I ran into an obscure bug in Websphere 6.12- that occurred when a JSTL function was executed in a tag body.  This is fixed in Websphere 6.13+, but not lower than 6.13.  As we use 6.11, we actually had to go and create custom tags for the functions we used, delegating to the actual code.

Comment: This sucks big cahones. Why the hell wont they let you invoke a method  using the class/instance itself!? You run into all kinds of wormholes on the JEE platform... ffs!

Answer (score 2):

To access the property of a bean using EL you simply name the property (not invoke the method). So lets say you have a method called getSize() in the bean then

```
${pageDividers.size}
```

Notice no ().

EDIT:Sorry...made an error in the original post.